# What is my username in Active Directory?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have a list of usernames `net user /domain`, which means my PC is in AD. `whoami` - `iis apppool\www.site.com`, `echo %USERNAME%` - `MyUsername123$`. There is no `www.site.com` or `MyUsername123$` in the list of AD users. My aim is to know my user permissions in AD `net user UserName /domain`.

P.S. It's a part of CTF cybersec game, so I don't have access to GUI, only CLI.

Comment: To be honest.. if it is part of CTF Game... have fun and good luck :) I don't think we should be helping you break in since it is a test of your own skill.

Answer (score 2):

'whoami' shows that your process is running as a local (non-domain) account. It's not a standard user account but an automatically managed "IIS application pool" account.

Because it's running under a non-AD account, the process only has Active Directory access using the computer's own *machine credentials*. In this case, `MyUsername123$` is the machine's AD account name (note the trailing $). Computer accounts are not shown in 'net user /dom'.

After trying to access an AD resource, use `klist` to see the Kerberos tickets available to the current process. The "Client" field will tell you exactly what AD account you're using.